Polynomial factorization using determinant
Algebraic identities
$$
P_2(a,b)=a^3+b^3=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab)
$$
$$
P_3(a,b,c)=a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-ac-bc)
$$
$$
P_4(a,b,c,d)=a^3+b^3+c^3+d^3-3abc-3abd-3acd-3bcd=(a+b+c+d)(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2-ab-ac-ad-bc-bd-cd)
$$
holds for any $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$. Polynomials $P_2,P_3, P_4$ are symmetric and similar identities could be derived using elementary symmetric polynomials for any polynomial $P_n$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$.
First and second of identities could be proven using circulant determinant and column property of determinants.
Polynomial $P_2$ and its expandet form:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&0\\
0&a&b\\
b&0&a\\
\end{vmatrix}
=a^3 + b^3
$$
Polynomial $P_2$ and its factored form (adding all columns to the first one):
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&0\\
0&a&b\\
b&0&a\\
\end{vmatrix}
= \begin{vmatrix}
a+b&b&0\\
a+b&a&b\\
a+b&0&a\\
\end{vmatrix}
=(a+b)(a^2+b^2-ab).
$$
Polynomial $P_3$ could be factored in similar fashion with circulant determinant
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c\\
c&a&b\\
b&c&a\\
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Any idea, how to prove factorization of polynomial $P_4$ using circulant determinant? Just to remind you: following determinant
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a&b&c&d\\
d&a&b&c\\
c&d&a&b\\
b&c&d&a\\
\end{vmatrix}
$$
equals fourth degree polynomial and not third degree polynomial $P_4$.
